# How to fix my Partition Scheme between SSD/HHD to Dual Boot W10/Ubuntu on SSD use Unified Storage

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, boot-partition

I use GRUB Loader to dual boot ubuntu and W10 at the moment. Ubuntu is definitely on SSD. I ended up accidentally installing W10 onto my HDD. I am not sure if W10 itself is on my SSD with Ubuntu or not. edit: [sudo update-grub results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tuv1.png) & 
 [partition scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfycS.png)

Is there a way to move W10 to the SSD if it is not there already without losing any of my preferences or applications? Can I reinstall a fresh W10 ISO on the SSD without losing ubuntu and then just restore from an external harddrive? What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Build:
MSI z270 SLI Plus Mobo,
Intel I7 4 core 7700 CPU,
NVIDIA MSI GeForce GPU,
16 GB RAM (ripjaw skills 8 x 2),
240 GB ADATA SSD (SATA 1),
1 TB WDC Internal HDD (SATA 2),
Corsair Liquid Cooling,
Intel BT/Wifi Adapter,
3 TB External Seagate HDD

Comment: You may want to delete part of your post and break it up into multiple questions.  This will get a lot more answers, and is the way things are meant to be done.  Also, its a good idea to remove extraneous information (like that you built a Mac, saying you are a noob etc)

Comment: "I am not sure if W10 itself is on my SSD with Ubuntu or not" You can check this running `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu. It will look for the installed OSs and tell you what disk they are on.